# how to access the formula of a $call function in R

Tags: r, formula, linear-regression, paste

I am using subset selection methods in the leaps package. After running subset selection, I can get the formula by accessing the `$call` variable stored in the object that I ran my subset selection (for this example, let's call the object `k`.

So if I run `k$call`, it will return a linear model formula, such as:

```
lm(formula = y + x1 + x2 + x3, data = trainingData)
```

Is there a way to run this formula by using `k$call`?

I tried running `lm.1 <- k$call` but it just stores the `k$call` instead of making the actual linear regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate the expression.

`eval(k$call)` will run the call

in your case

```
lm.1 <- evalk$call
```